# Show image inside JQuery Mobile PopUp

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile PopUp control inside a dynamic table to let user view image in PopUp. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>


while($FormDataRow = mysql_fetch_array($formDataSQLObj))
{
$Imagepath = "Uploaded_Fotos/";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
?>
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">
<img src="<?php echo $Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]; ?>" width="100px"/>
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
<img src="<?php echo $Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]; ?>" />
</div>
<?php
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

The image appear fine inside table but popup shows empty when we click on image.

What's missing?

Comment: which popup js you are using is it mobile friendly?

Comment: The problem resides within the way the `php` and jquery are interacting. Maybe a minor error. Can you post the jquery also? Should you assign a class to the images for selecting?

Comment: see my edit... I have put jquery references above.

Comment: where is the js which initiates the popup ?

Comment: That's the jquery included, Where's the plugin and the 5 or 6 lines or code need to initialise the pop-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using same `id` for multiple images this may be a issue because id is supposed to be a unique so in your code i notice the id is same for each image will not gonna work try this

```
$index=1;
while($FormDataRow = mysql_fetch_array($formDataSQLObj))
{
$Imagepath = "Uploaded_Fotos/";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
?>
<a href="#popupBasic_<?php echo index;?>" data-rel="popup">
<img src="<?php echo $Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]; ?>" width="100px"/>
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic_<?php echo index;?>">
<img src="<?php echo $Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]; ?>" />
</div>
<?php
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
$index++;
}
```